# Rendering HTML to PDF with images included Django

Tags: javascript, django, pdf, jspdf

I have a django app where users would print some pages which include images as a part of Data processing.

I tried jsPDF but it didn't render my images and I ended up with just text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pdfDownloader").click(function() {

    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);

    doc.fromHTML($('#renderMe').get(0), 15, 15, {
      'width': 500
    }, function (dispose) {
    doc.save('thisMotion.pdf');
    });
  });
})
```

This was my code and it didn't render the images so do I need to change anything?

is using a Django view would solve this and is there any alternatives to `xhtml2pdf` as with this I need to include my CSS in the HTML file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fromHTML** is used to get text from the HTML to form a PDF. Try using html2canvas js library instead.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

You can create a canvas image and add it to the PDF with code like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pdfDownloader").click(function() {

html2canvas($("#renderMe")).then(canvas => {  
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4', true); // A4 size page of PDF  
      var positionX = 0;  
      var positionY = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', positionY, positionY, undefined, undefined)  
      pdf.save('thisMotion.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });

});
})
```

This will get you a PDF just like the HTML rendered on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it but my pdf is always truncated not showing the whole #renderme div and even truncated when I tried to change the pdf page size to a3 for example and the pdf was somewhat low quality.

Comment: That's a bummer. But here's something if you wanna try it. Instead of mentioning 'a3' or 'a4' you can give manual input like `let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'px',[760,1094], true);` This allows you to twerk the page size to your need. And as far as the quality is concerned, there's a parameter called **scale** which allows you to improve the quality. I hope this helps.

Comment: would changing the page size to something like this would fix the issue? I mean what's the reason for something like this in the first place, btw I really appreciate your help if that didn't work I guess I will accept the answer and try making it by a Django view using a python library like reportlab or something but I hoped that I would make it by a js.
Thanks.

Comment: I understand. I had an similar issue. I used the [760,1094] to get my web page onto the PDF. Its configurable. You may use any values in it.